# Where i can find source code of method map?

Tags: scala

I am studying CanBuildFrom, and I know that this mechanism is used to create collections that need to be returned as a result of executing the map(...) method. I want to read the source code, but I can't find it in the standard library.

Comment: A web search turned up this [Github reference](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/v2.12.10/src/library/scala/collection/generic/CanBuildFrom.scala#L33).

Comment: This is not what I'm looking for, it's googled in the dock itself with a direct link to the source code. But I couldn't find the source code of the map() method.

Comment: Just so you know, `CanBuildFrom` is gone from the standard library since 2.13.

Comment: Which version of Scala are you asking about, and which collection?

Comment: Exact implementation depends on the collection. [Here](https://github.com/scala/scala/blob/2.13.x/src/library/scala/collection/immutable/List.scala#L244) is the one for `List` for Scala 2.13

Comment: We use Scala 2.12 in work.